# Is $\mathfrak p=\omega_1$ equivalent to the existence of a Hausdorff gap without infinite pseudointersection?

Tags: set-theory, independence-results, cardinal-characteristics

Given two set $A,B$ we write $A\subset^* B$ if the complement $A\setminus B$ is infinite.

---

A *Hausdorff gap* is a transfinite family $\langle A_\alpha,B_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha\in\omega_1}$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ satisfying the following two properties:

$\bullet$ $A_\alpha\subset^* A_\beta\subset^* B_\beta\subset^* B_\alpha$ for any countable ordinals $\alpha\le\beta$;

$\bullet$ for any infinite subset $I\subset \omega$ there exists a countable ordinal $\alpha$ such that $A_\alpha\not\subset^* I$ or $I\not\subset^* B_\alpha$.

---

A in infinite subset $I\subset\omega$ is called a *pseudointersection* of a Hausdorff gap $\langle A_\alpha,B_\alpha\rangle_{\alpha\in\omega_1}$ if $I\subset^* (B_\alpha\setminus A_\alpha)$ for any $\alpha\in\omega_1$.

---

[The definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-intersection) of the small uncountable cardinal $\mathfrak p$ implies that under $\mathfrak p>\omega_1$ each Hausdorff gap has an infinite pseudointersection.

What does happen under $\mathfrak p=\omega_1$?

> **Problem.** Is $\mathfrak p=\omega_1$ equivalent to the existence of a Hausdorff gap without infinite pseudointersection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  This is a result due to Nyikos and Vaughan from 1983, appearing the paper

*Nyikos, Peter J.; Vaughan, Jerry E.*, [**On first countable, countably compact spaces. I: ((\omega_ 1,\omega^*_ 1))-gaps**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1999547), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 279, 463-469 (1983). [ZBL0542.54004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0542.54004).

Hausdorff gaps without a pseudo-intersection are called *tight* gaps, and Theorem 1.2 of the paper shows that these exist if and only if $\mathfrak{p}=\omega_1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was very helpful!